# BIGQUERY Sum Col1 based on unique entries in Col2 and on specific date

Tags: sum, duplicates, bq

I am trying to sum a column1 (invoice_value) in BQ based on a specific date but I want to avoid the duplicates in Column2 (invoice_no).

So far I can sum the column1, but the total sum I get includes several duplicates in column2 (invoice_no)

SELECT SUM(invoices_value) as INVOICES FROM `my_data`
WHERE invoice_value IS NOT NULL
AND timestamp >='2021-03-01'
AND timestamp < '2021-03-02'

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Champion!!! That worked. Now one last improvement, how can I automate the date to always be yesterday or today-1?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query to remove duplicates records

```
SELECT SUM(invoices_value) as INVOICES FROM 
(SELECET DISTINCT invoices_value, invoice_no, timestamp FROM my_data )
WHERE invoice_value IS NOT NULL 
AND CAST(timestamp AS TIMESTAMP) >=TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
AND CAST (timestamp AS TIMESTAMP) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

Comment: Now how can I automate the date to always be yesterday or today-1?